# PNChart and UIStackview Issues using storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, xcode-storyboard, uistackview

I'm having difficulty using the PNChart (https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart) library with storyboards and uistackviews. I'm expecting the chart to simply fill the space of an existing uiview which I'm adding the pnchart to in code. However the chart is displaying off the screen, instead of within the bounds of the uiview.

Here is a screenshot of the issue - note I have made the UIView that I'm adding the chart to blue so I can see it has the correct layout. As you can see the chart is much bigger than the uiview it is added to and you are unable to see the y elements nor the entire chart.

[image]

Here is my storyboard structure
[image]

- Graph View is a UIView - I am adding the PNChart as a subview of this. Here is my code:

> ```
> CGRect graphViewFrame = _graphView.frame;
> PNLineChart * lineChart = [[PNLineChart alloc] initWithFrame:graphViewFrame];
> [lineChart setXLabels:@[@"SEP 1",@"SEP 2",@"SEP 3",@"SEP 4",@"SEP 5"]];
>
> // Line Chart No.1
> NSArray * data01Array = @[@60.1, @160.1, @126.4, @262.2, @186.2];
> PNLineChartData *data01 = [PNLineChartData new];
> data01.color = PNFreshGreen;
> data01.itemCount = lineChart.xLabels.count;
> data01.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
>         CGFloat yValue = [data01Array[index] floatValue];
>         return [PNLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
> };
> // Line Chart No.2
> NSArray * data02Array = @[@20.1, @180.1, @26.4, @202.2, @126.2];
> PNLineChartData *data02 = [PNLineChartData new];
> data02.color = PNTwitterColor;
> data02.itemCount = lineChart.xLabels.count;
> data02.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
>     CGFloat yValue = [data02Array[index] floatValue];
>     return [PNLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
> };
>
> lineChart.chartData = @[data01, data02];
> [lineChart strokeChart];
> [_graphView addSubview:lineChart];
> ```

Here are the details on the stack view 
[image]

Any ideas or recommendations appreciated. I have already contacted the developer of PNChart.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using size classes? 
Check that the first frame that you get and use, is really the frame that you would expect after the view was presented. If you are using Xib for example, the frame before and after "viewDidApear" are diffrent with every screen size.

Secound, use "clipToBounds" to make sure the graph is not drawing out of your bounds that is set.

```
self.lineChart.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Good luck

Comment: I tired clips to bounds but that didn't help. I'm not using size classes....as far as I know.

Comment: 1.Did you use the clip to bounds before "strokeChart"?  2. The lines: [lineChart strokeChart];
[_graphView addSubview:lineChart] :  You should first add as subview and then call stroke. 3. Try to use debug tools to see if the frame changes, I had the same problem in the past with the PNCharts, and that was it

Comment: The problem is that clipToBounds clips the chart, I want it to (resize / fit) within the bounds of the parent uiview

Comment: Here's what I get when analysing the UI in Xcode and printing PNChart frame information: <PNLineChart: 0x7ce915a0; frame = (0 26; 288 100); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7af879b0>>

Comment: You are trying to draw the chart before the view knows the exact size of screen. Try to call "strokeChart" only after "viewDidApear" method if called by the parent ViewController, and see if the size will be right. If my assomption is right. The size should be what you expect. Then you will have two options, 1. to set the frame progrematicly by perspective to the UIScreen. 2. To wait till the view is set for drawing.

Comment: Thanks...I'll try that and report back. Thanks for coming back to me.

Comment: Same issue. So what I've done is have chart setup code in viewDidLoad and chart stroke in viewDidAppear - same outcome. I have a bigger issue here. If I switch to FSLineChart I get the same problem. I had a go at using stack views with the FSLineChart demo app and it works ok. So the problem is somewhere in my app. I've compared the setup of storyboards and they're identical so I may need to contact apple support for this one.

Comment: Thanks for all your help though...unless you have a thought on where else to start looking into this issue?

Comment: Try to create and stroke after viewDidApear! It will shoild work, you are setting the frame, when the frame isn't valid yet. I have used PNChart, had the same issue and fixed it. FSLineChart doesn't draw itself with animation if I'm recall currectly.

Comment: When working with storyboard and frames, you somthing get thes kind of problems. But like I sad if you simply use the screen bounds ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.4) insted of setting to the parent view frame, when the frame is'nt yet set. You should be fine. But test me first, try to set the frame and draw after ViewDidApear. It should work.

Comment: And if this will not help (and I realy dont think it will not), maybe you should post a sample project with this issue.